# docker desktop Cannot load builder default *: permission denied

Tags: linux, docker, docker-desktop

This is a problem for a docker expert.

I have:

- Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
- Docker desktop v4.26.0
- Docker version 24.0.7, build afdd53b

I have problems running `docker build` commands. It starts working but it gets stuck in some point. It's not related to the Dockerfile. It randomly get stuck.

I discovered that it fails **ONLY if I have docker-desktop enabled.** If I stop docker-desktop service, the `docker build` works.
So, the problem is related with docker-desktop 100% sure.

If I run `docker builder ls` I got this:

```
NAME/NODE       DRIVER/ENDPOINT STATUS  BUILDKIT             PLATFORMS
default *       docker                                       
  default       default         running v0.11.7+d3e6c1360f6e linux/amd64, linux/amd64/v2, linux/amd64/v3, linux/386
desktop-linux   docker                                       
  desktop-linux desktop-linux   running v0.11.7+d3e6c1360f6e linux/amd64, linux/amd64/v2, linux/amd64/v3, linux/arm64, linux/riscv64, linux/ppc64le, linux/s390x, linux/386, linux/mips64le, linux/mips64, linux/arm/v7, linux/arm/v6
```

I also run:
`docker builder use default`

BUT, in the **docker-desktop interface** -> **Builders** Menu I see an error:

- builder: **desktop-linux** : Running
- builder: **default**: Error

```
permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get "http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/_ping": dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
```

Notes:

- I have a lot of CPU, memory and disk resources in docker desktop.
- I already run `sudo usermod -aG docker ${USER} && newgrp docker` and restart the system.
- I already fully remove docker and docker-desktop, and try to install ONLY docker-desktop alone and it's the same problem.

If I select the **builder with ERROR** inside docker-dektop and click the button **USE**, it works! But I don't want to do this any time I open docker-desktop. I would like to have it has default forever.

Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: If you're on a native-Linux host, do you actually need Docker Desktop (which launches a Linux VM to run containers, even on a Linux host)?